# the virus pop - the virus population?

Tags: word-meaning

Does "the virus pop" refer to "the virus population"?

> sierra_iola tweeted today:

> mRNA vaccines have been tested for years (it’s how we got this one up and running so fast). If you’re worried about side effects in the vax population you should REALLY be paying attention to **the virus pop**. As the early inflammation signs are terrifying.

[Source](https://twitter.com/Sierra_Iola/status/1336217313046110210)

Comment: "pop" definitely stands for "population". Remember that Twitter messages have a size limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means "the virus population", but it doesn't mean how many viruses there are, but the population who have the virus, that is, all of the people who have or will get the virus.

So, if you are worried about the side effects of the vaccine, compare them to the effects of the virus itself.
Then the vaccine side effects won't seem so severe.